# Windows 10 - python pip not working (with env vars added)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

On Windows 10, with both Python 2.7 and 3.6 versions installed, and apparently all required paths added to the environment variables, pip still isn't recognised.

(Btw, when I run the python command, it shows I'm using 3.6)

My scripts folders include pip.exe, pip3.exe, pip3.6.exe.

And my environmental variables look something like this:

```
PATH=...;%PYTHON3%;%PYTHON2%;...

Where:
PYTHON2=C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs
PYTHON3=C:\Python36;C:\Python36\Scripts;C:\Python36\lib\site-packages;C:\Python36\Lib;C:\Python36\DLLs;C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36;C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts
```

I've tried various permutations of the following:

```
pip
pip3
python3 pip
python3 pip3
py pip
py pip3
```

But each time I get an error message similar to the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  File "C:\Python36\pip3.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Any ideas how I can get pip working?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to install a module, from the command line.
However, whatever I do doesn't seem to get pip recognised.

Comment: The "Lib", "Lib\site-packages", and "DLLs" directories do not belong in `PATH`. Remove them.  Offhand I don't see how that would break pip3.exe, but let's start there. Also make sure you do not have `PYTHONPATH` or `PYTHONHOME` set; they're rarely needed.

Comment: Even if I cd to C:\Python36\Scripts where I can see all the .exe files (eg. pip.exe), then run pip install sphinx, I still get the same error: ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'pip'.

Comment: @eryksun, thanks I've removed those three folders.
I've no PYTHONPATH OR PYTHONHOME...just the PYTHON3 path (which I assume is possibly the same issue...but I've used it so I can easily switch between the two Python versions)

Comment: There shouldn't be a "pip3.exe" in the "Python36" installation directory. Please re-run the 3.6 installer and make sure you have the option selected to install pip properly.

Comment: Also, if you're using the py launcher, it's `py -m pip`. The *module* name is always just "pip", and `-m` runs a module as a script.

Comment: @eryksun. Looks like you got it.  I uninstalled and re-ran the Python36 installation, clicked add the paths and its working now.

I suspect I missed the tickbox to add the paths before, and then added them manually.  As a result, I could have been missing a correct path for the %appdata% address, which has this: \Python36-32\Scripts\.

(ie. I was missing the -32 part)

Comment: More likely pip wasn't installed properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187255/discussion-between-christo-and-eryksun).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got it working.

As per the comments from eryksun, I  uninstalled and re-ran the Python36 installation, and made sure to click the box to add the paths.  Thereafter it worked.

For background, I believe I missed the tickbox to add the paths before. I did notice there were no pip.exe files in the Scripts folder ('perhaps' that was a result of failing to tick add paths).

And when I noticed the missing pip files, I tried a manual installation via the https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py  script.  So that's how I ended up with a bunch of pip.exes, but couldn't get pip to work.

Anyway, reinstalling and ticking the add paths box worked.

Comment: yup can do, but according to a pink message that appeared, I have to wait till tomorrow...

Answer (score 1):

You are running this from `python`.

You need run it from `CMD` or `Powershell`

<kbd>*Windows logo*</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

```
type cmd
```

<kbd>enter</kbd>

```
pip install <module>
```

Comment: I've tried CMD and Git Bash, even running them as Admin. But I still get the same error: no module named 'pip'.

Comment: If you are running this from `cmd`, did should say `"pip" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` and then we have another problem

Comment: @Carcigenicate, it's a traceback from the "\_\_main\_\_.py" script that's embedded in pip3.exe. An entry-point launcher such as pip3.exe contains a shebang with the fully-qualified path of python.exe and a little script that imports the entry-point function from the module, modifies `sys.argv`, and calls the function as `sys.exit(entrypoint_function())`. If it can't import pip because it's not installed properly, then `ModuleNotFoundError` is exactly what we expect to observe.